# DOM Inspector's Firefox plugin doesn't highlight the web elements

Tags: browser-addons, firefox-extensions, firefox

I use the Firefox plugin named [DOM Inspector version 2.0.10](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) with Firefox 6.0.2.

When I click on a node the corresponding element is not highlighted on my web page.
It used to work with previous versions of Firefox.

Does anyone know how to make it work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be the [following workaround](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/):

> You can turn-off *hardware-acceleration* in Firefox: options > advance > general

If that doesn't work, it's simply a compatibility issue, and I would contact the developers to update their plugin.

---

If you need something like DOM Inspector, why not use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) instead?

> The most popular and powerful web development tool:
>
> - Inspect HTML and modify style and layout in real-time
> - Use the most advanced JavaScript debugger available for any browser
> - Accurately analyze network usage and performance

Comment: Thanks your tip, it works well!!! I'll try Firebug to see if it matches my needs.